# Eclipse 'unable to write jarlist cache' error

Tags: android, eclipse, caching

I keep getting this 'unable to write jarlist cache' error. I have checked for updates, there are non. And re-added the reference libraries from properties. Still getting same error...

Answer (score 0):

Might be, a the API would not be supported by the app.

**Select Project --> Properties --> Android**
and choose a lower API.

Also try,
**Project --> Properties --> Clean**

The Facebook sdk does not support API 8. Select the project, click on Project>Properties > Android and choose a lower API. If an error persists, try Project >Properties > Clean.

Might not be necessary, but still, it is advisable to confirm if write permissions are available.